# The parameter value must be between '0' and '35791.3940666667'

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I'm trying to scale a TextBlock's font size (WPF) according to it's width.
The problem is that I get this error:

> The parameter value must be between '0' and '35791.3940666667'. Parameter name: paragraphProperties.DefaultTextRunProperties.FontRenderingEmSize

This error only happens when the TextBlock's text is defined within the .xaml file and works flawlessly if the text is yet to be known (bound using data binding).

**Here is the xaml code causing the error:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FontSizeScale" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={x:Static localConverter:WidthToFontSizeConverter.Instance}}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="715*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="220*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="17*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="371*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="36*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="87*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FontSizeScale}" Text="Version: " FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

**Here is WidthToFontSizeConverter class:**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class WidthToFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly WidthToFontSizeConverter Instance = new WidthToFontSizeConverter();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double) value / 1.7;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Here is the code with data binding (no errors, works flawlessly):**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FontSizeScale" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={x:Static localConverter:WidthToFontSizeConverter.Instance}}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="715*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="220*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="17*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="371*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="36*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="87*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FontSizeScale}" Text="{Binding Version}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7

Comment: Log to console values from `value / 1.7;` and see what it calculated. Look for large numbers, negatives, infinities and NaN and NULLs. I'm pretty sure that ActualWidth/ActualHeight can have transient unstable values that you wouldn't expect, but I can't tell you what exactly it can be.. I just remember it sometimes is nonsense for a few milliseconds, but that impacts such immediate-converters.

Comment: You are right. For some reason the 'value' just keeps growing (or changing) infinitely.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? ActualWidth would increase the FontSize, which in turn would increase ActualWidth, ad infinitum.

Comment: The width changes when the user resizes the windows. What I want to do is to keep the scale even if the width is really small or big. 'ActualWidth' is the as the name suggests. while 'Width' is the width that was given in the xaml which is constant.